# Maintaining aspect ratio with min/max height/width?

Tags: html, css, sass, aspect-ratio

I have a gallery on my site where users can upload images.

I would like the images to sit in a div that maintains its height, the images should be no larger than 500px in height. The width should be automatic to maintain aspect ratio.

HTML:

```
<div id="gallery">
    <img src="uploads/my-dynamic-img.jpg">
</div>
```

I've tried this CSS:

```
#gallery{
    height: 500px;

    img{
        max-height: 500px;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
}
```

The above works well, the gallery is always 500px high and images never exceed 500px in height. I run into problems though with smaller images, if a user uploads a really small image, I would like it 'blown up' to a minimum of 200px. I know this can be achieved by setting a `min-height` on the image, the problem with this is, if the image is less than 200px in height but say, 2000px wide, the image gets blown up to 200px in height, but then the aspect ratio is screwed, as the image is wider than the images parent div.

How can I have a min height but retain aspect ratio?

Comment: That's not CSS syntax -- are you using a language like SASS or Stylus or is that just an error?

Comment: The first thing that comes to my mind is using background images with background-size: contain, but that wouldn't work if you need to cover <= IE8.

Comment: if you have control over the html output, use server-side processing to determine the aspect ratio, then add a "wide" or "tall" class and handle their styling separately. If you don't have control over html, than use javascript to do the same thing, and again, style them separately.

Answer (score 46):

The property you're looking for is `object-fit`.  This is one of Opera's innovations, you can read more about it in their [2011 dev article on object-fit](https://dev.opera.com/articles/css3-object-fit-object-position/) (yep, it's been around that long).  A few years ago, I wouldn't have been able to recommend it to you, but caniuse shows that everyone else is starting to catch up:

- Opera 10.6-12.1 (-o- prefix)
- Chrome 31+
- Opera 19+
- Safari 7.1+
- iOS 8+
- Android 4.4+

http://caniuse.com/#search=object-fit

```
#gallery img {
    -o-object-fit: contain;
    object-fit: contain;
}
```

Using a value of `contain` will force the image to maintain its aspect ratio no matter what.

Alternately, you might want to use this instead:

```
#gallery img {
    -o-object-fit: cover;
    object-fit: cover;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

http://sassmeister.com/gist/9b130efdae95bfa4338e

Comment: As of Microsoft Edge, this still has not been implemented. However, they state that it is under consideration for Edge. [https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/objectfitandobjectposition/](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/objectfitandobjectposition/)

Comment: One problem with this sullotion is that it only forces the actual image and not the img-tag to contain proportions, so if you for example put a border on the image tag it won't keep the proportions: https://jsfiddle.net/pwxca5af/

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly if you want to define places were will be an image but you still haven't load it yet because of network delay. I'm combining it with lazy load on a big grid of 4x20 image elements.

Comment: @brsfan it seems that today Edge has object-fit implemented. It works!

Answer (score 7):

The only way that I know of to possibly accomplish this is by setting either the `width` or `height` to `auto`.

```
#gallery{
    height: 500px;

    img{
        max-height: 500px;
        width: auto;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is possible using only CSS.

However, you may be able to accomplish the same thing with a few lines of JavaScript:

```
var img= document.querySelectorAll('img');
for(var i = 0 ; i < img.length ; i++) {
  img[i].onload= function() {
    var h= this.naturalHeight;
    h= Math.min(500,Math.max(200,h));
    this.style.height= h+'px';
  }
}
```

This sets the height of all images to be between 200px and 500px.  The width will automatically be scaled.

```js
var img= document.querySelectorAll('img');
for(var i = 0 ; i < img.length ; i++) {
  img[i].onload= function() {
    var h= this.naturalHeight;
    h= Math.min(500,Math.max(200,h));
  }
}
```

```css
#gallery{
  height: 500px;
  width: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="gallery">
  <img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-logo-med.png">

</div>
```

Comment: I left out `this.naturalHeight` from my original post, so the image height would always be *either* 200px *or* 500px.  Now it can take on values in between.

Answer (score 0):

I've been meaning to do something similar, actually. Here's something in jQuery if you're into that.

SCSS:

```
#gallery {
  height: 500px;

  img {
    max-height: 100%;
  }

  .small {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
    height: auto;
  }

  .regular {
    width: auto;
    min-height: 200px;
  }
}
```

jQuery:

```
$( 'img' ).each( function() {

  var imageWidth = parseFloat( $( this ).css( 'width' ) );
  var imageHeight = parseFloat( $( this ).css( 'height' ) );

  if( imageHeight <= 200 && imageWidth >= 200 ) {
    $( this ).addClass( 'small' );
  }
  else {
    $( this ).addClass( 'regular' );
  }
});
```

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/dustindowell22/pen/bNdGRM)