# Aspect Ratio Fill - the right way

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know, it has been asked before. The answers are insufficient although they are marked as correct.

I need something that fills a container with an image by showing the most of the image, centers it and preserves its ratio. Should be ajquery-plugin, a angular-directive or plain JS.

```
<div ratio-fill>
  <img>
</div>
```

Of course should be enough where the script takes action then.

---

Solution for interest:

```
  <div ratio-fill="http://img.url"></div>
```

CSS

```
  *[ratio-fill] { background-size: cover;
    background-position: center; }
```

Script (jQuery)

```
  /* img-ratio-fill */
  $(window).load(function(){

   /* ratio-fill-directive */
   $('*[ratio-fill]').each(function() { 

      var $this = $(this),
          imgUrl = $this.attr( "ratio-fill" );

      $this.css( "background-image", "url('" + imgUrl + "')" );

    });

  })
```

Comment: Can you use `background-size: cover` instead?

Comment: Does this do what you want? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18490334/responsive-image-full-screen-and-centered-maintain-aspect-ratio-not-exceed-wi

Comment: Can you clarify specifically which answers are insufficient and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with css on the DIV
background-size: cover; background-position: center;